# Put my date into date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

EDIT: I'm sorry if Misleading you, I am attaching the question again

i have Date Picker in my jQuery-Mobile page

i work with: **jQuery 1.8.3** and **jQuery Mobile 1.2.0**

```
<label for="MyDate" style="text-align:right">Insert Date</label>
<input type="date" name="MyDate" id="MyDate">
```

i need to setup the date to 01/05/2003 (for example when i press any button on my page)

html

```
<label for="MyDate" style="text-align:right">Insert Date</label>
<input type="date" name="MyDate" id="MyDate">
 <p id="res">res</p>
```

JS

```
var yourDate='01/05/2003'
$("#MyDate").val(yourDate);
$('#res').text(yourDate);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/goldsoft/mgxabwej/2/

Comment: What have you done to try and achieve this? We don't produce code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method **[setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)** of datepicker:

```
$('selector').datepicker('setDate', '01/05/2013');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you set your input `type="date"` when it should be `type="text"`. Further, you have to initialize the datepicker object first.

```
<label for="MyDate" style="text-align:right">Insert Date</label>
<input type="text" name="MyDate" id="MyDate">

$('#MyDate').datepicker();
$('#MyDate').datepicker('setDate', '01/05/2013');
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ks1cwfzL/)

Comment: i work ok jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery MObile 1.2.0 and It does not work at all

Answer (score 0):

You can sipmly do

```
var yourDate='01/05/2013';
$("#MyDate").val(yourDate);
```

And here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mgxabwej/1/